# Finding an additive generator of a finite field

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

There's quite a lot of literature about how to find a generator of the multiplicative subgroup of a finite field $\mathbb{F}$.

A much simpler question: can we find an additive generator $a$?  So that $\{ a, a + a, a + a + a, ...\} = \mathbb{F}$?

Comment: don't forget that $p\times a=0$ if the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is $p$.

Comment: There only exists additive generations for prime fields, and then it is any non-zero element. For fields with the size of other prime powers, there cannot be an additive generator.

Comment: Could you tell us what your thoughts and solution attempts are behind it, so that we can not only solve the task, but also really help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is equivalent to asking [whether a finite field is a cyclic additive group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391897/is-every-finite-field-a-cyclic-additive-group).

Finite prime fields are cyclic additive groups.  Extension fields are not.

Comment: The term "prime field" usually means a field with no proper subfields, so $\mathbf{Q}$ is also a prime field, and its additive group is not cyclic.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: "**Finite** prime field, has written @Matthias, not simply prime field.